# QTableView and set pointer position

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView with some data. Data sometimes changes, and then I need refresh TableView. After refresh, cursor lose position. If it was in 5 position(row), after refresh is out of tableview(or on first row). I want it back on 5, but it does not work.

I saved last position by "`index = ui->tableView->currentIndex()`" and get it back by "`ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(index)`"

What's wrong?

```
//save last cursor(row) position
QModelIndex index = ui->tableView->currentIndex();

//create basic model with my data
myModel = new MyModel();

//insert my model to sortfilterproxymodel and then sort it
QSortFilterProxyModel *sort_filter = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
sort_filter->setSourceModel(myModel);
sort_filter->setSortCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
sort_filter->sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);       //sort by name
sort_filter->sort(5, Qt::DescendingOrder);      //sort by surename

//insert my data to tableview
ui->tableView->setModel(sort_filter);
ui->tableView->hideColumn(5);

//return it back to its original position
ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `setModel`, you update the model, and thus your index may no longer be valid:

> Note: Model indexes should be used immediately and then discarded. You
>   should not rely on indexes to remain valid after calling model
>   functions that change the structure of the model or delete items. If
>   you need to keep a model index over time use a QPersistentModelIndex.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#details

Comment: Ok, so how can I set a pointer to a specific position. Because through QModelIndex index = ui->tableView->currentIndex(); int row = index.row(); I know the last active position.

Comment: You can use the `row()` value to get a new `QModelIndex` from your model via `index(...)` and use that for `setCurrentIndex()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still have a problem. I made this construction `QPoint point(row, 0);`  `index = ui->tableView->indexAt(point);`  `ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(index);`. Now row is selected, but on wrong position. Always stay on first visible row.

Comment: Why use `QPoint`? If you do that, you need to know the height of all rows in front of the row you want to select. Just generate a new index from `myModel`. Or `ui->tableView->model()->index(row, 0)` (assuming `model()` does not return a `nullptr`).

Comment: Super! Thank you very much.